# How to replace inner content of a class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have used a class 4 times in a page and I want to replace the content from one of them by using JavaScript

Here is the code of my html

```
<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Publisher Solutions</a></span>

<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Social Media 360</a></span>

<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Partnerships</a></span>

<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Brown Bag Presentations</a></span>
```

and I want to change like this

```
<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Publisher Solutions</a></span>

<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Social Media 360</a></span>

<span class="footer"><a href="link.html">Partnerships</a></span>

<span class="footer"><a href="edited_link_from_js.html">Custom New Text From js</a></span>
```

Comment: What are you using to determine which one to change? Is the choice of which to change dynamic at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this fits?

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("footer");
var elem = elems[3];
elem.firstChild.href="edited_link_from_js.html";
elem.firstChild.innerHTML="My new text";
```

Here I manually select the 4th one, but you can change by `elems.lenght - 1` if you always want last, or any selector you need.

Comment: Don't forget the text-node contained in that <a> tag (`Brown Bag Presentations` should become `Custom New Text From js`)

Comment: thanks @Aryess and enhzflep , one more thing - If I want to remove the <a> tag entirely so what I have to write in js

Comment: elem.remove(elem.firstChild);